# kubernetes redis-cluster pod by pod login using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, redis-cluster, redis-cli

Currently, I am trying to prepare a shell script for redis-cluster backup of each pod running in a particular namespace.

I wanted to achieve it by performing two operations:

1. login to each pod one by one and then connect to redis-cli and execute BGSAVE command.
2. take a copy of dump.rdb file from each pod and place it at backup folder.

for first part, I have prepared following code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
NS=$1
for i in `cat "$NS"_POD_LIST`;
do
  echo "POD: $i";
  kubectl exec -it $i -n $NS -- bash -c "redis-cli -c BGSAVE"
  ##After BGSAVE wanted to get out of redis-cli, but it get stuck here, unable to switch to other pod
done
```

now on the second part wanted to copy dump.rdb file from each pod to the destination folder, but this execution will be outside of pod..

```
SOURCE_DIR="/redis/data"
BACKUP_DIR="/pod/backup"
for i in `cat "$NS"_POD_LIST`;
do
  echo "POD: $i";
  kubectl cp $NS/$i:$SOURCE_DIR $BACKUP_DIR
done
```

Please let me know on this code snippet how to achieve this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your `"$NS"_POD_LIST` variable with us ?
What do you mean by `it get stuck here, unable to switch to other pod`, can you display script output ?
Are you able to run single `kubectl exec -it $i -n $NS -- bash -c "redis-cli -c BGSAVE"` command without any issues ?

Comment: This will list all the pods in namespace line by line... For example in a namespace of three pods running, then it will be list- pod-0, pod-1, pod-2  all in new line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you answer the rest of my questions ?
Are you able to run `kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> -n <NAMESPACE> -- bash -c "redis-cli -c BGSAVE"` from the command line without any issues ?
Can you display script output ?